# How to use Comma Separated String with switch statement

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement, explode

I have a string `$str="1,2,4";`

Also I have a switch statement

```
                    switch ($str_value) {
                        case '0':
                            $finalday='Sunday';
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            $finalday='Monday';
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            $finalday='Tuesday';
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            $finalday='Wednesday';
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            $finalday='Thursday';
                            break;
                        case '5':
                            $finalday='Friday';
                            break;
                        case '6':
                            $finalday='Saturday';
                            break;
                        default: $finalday='';
                    }
```

Using this statement from given string I want to show result

as `Day is :  Monday,Tuesday,Thursday`

how can I do that?

Comment: I thought php had associative arrays :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `switch` case make an array of days

```
$days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Saturday'];
$str="1,2,4";
$val = [];
foreach(explode(',',$str) as $value){
    $val[] = $days[$value];
}
echo implode(',',$val);//Monday,Tuesday,Thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a switch statement. Use preg_replace:

```
$final_day = $str_value;
$final_day = preg_replace('/0/', 'Sunday', $final_day);
// ...
$final_day = preg_replace('/6/', 'Saturday', $final_day);
```

And you have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the switch statement, explode the string into an array:

```
myDays = explode(",", $str);
```

Then loop over myDays with the switch statement in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` and pass a `$days` array to it.
That'll get the required digit(using the regex) and return day from the `$days` array.
Something like this -

```
$days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
preg_replace_callback('/\d+/',function($m)use($days){return $days[$m[0]];}, $str)

#OUTPUTS - 
"Monday,Tuesday,Thursday"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
<?php

$str='1,2,3';

$array=explode(',',$str);

$finalday='';

foreach($array as $a){

switch ($a) {
                case '0':
                    $finalday.=',Sunday';
                    break;
                case '1':
                    $finalday.=',Monday';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $finalday.=',Tuesday';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $finalday.=',Wednesday';
                    break;
                case '4':
                    $finalday.=',Thursday';
                    break;
                case '5':
                    $finalday.=',Friday';
                    break;
                case '6':
                    $finalday.=',Saturday';
                    break;
                default: $finalday='';
               }

}

echo substr($finalday,1);
```